# Node js peerwire protocol implementation

Tags: node.js, bittorrent, torrent, peer-wire-protocol

While implementing Bittorrent prtotocol, to communicate with peers and get pieces run into problem with some incoming peer messages:
buffer of such messages contain about 200 "255" values and then, about 200 random numbers. The problem is that i can't find in specification definition for such payload. Type of message described by first or fourth byte in buffer, any way in my situation both of them are equal to 255, and there is no such type of message (available types are: 1-8, 16, 21-23)

Array representation of the buffer:

```
[255,255,255,255,255,239,254,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,247,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,223,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,254,255,255,255,239,255,254,237,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,239,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,251,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,253,191,255,255,255,255,255,255,253,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,249,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,247,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,254,191,255,127,255,247,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,0,0,0,5,4,0,0,3,11,0,0,0,5,4,0,0,5,196,0,0,0,5,4,0,0,1,186,0,0,0,5,4,0,0,2,102,0,0,0,5,4,0,0,2,95,0,0,0,5,4,0,0,6,7,0,0,0,5,4,0,0,4,30,0,0,0,5,4,0,0,4,190,0,0,0,5,4,0,0,4,189,0,0,0,5,4,0,0,2,47,0,0,0,5,4,0,0,1,19,0,0,0,5,4,0,0,0,28,0,0,0,5,4,0,0,0,223,0,0,0,5,4,0,0,2,75,0,0,0,5,4,0,0,4,33,0,0,0,5,4,0,0,1,31,0,0,0,5,4,0,0,1,100,0,0,0,5,4,0,0,6,24,0,0,0,5,4,0,0,3,181,0,0,0,5,4,0,0,4,94,0,0,0,5,4,0,0,2,99,0,0,0,5,4,0,0,6,44,0,0,0,5,4,0,0,0,74,0,0,0,5,4,0,0,6,9,0,0,0,1,1]
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have is a **bitfield** message missing the beginning with the length, type and probably some of the data, 24 **have** messages and one **unchoke** message.

```
255,255,255,255,255,239,254,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,247,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,223,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,254,255,255,255,239,255,254,237,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,239,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,251,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,253,191,255,255,255,255,255,255,253,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,249,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,247,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,254,191,255,127,255,247,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,
0,0,0,5,4,0,0,3,11,
0,0,0,5,4,0,0,5,196,
0,0,0,5,4,0,0,1,186,
0,0,0,5,4,0,0,2,102,
0,0,0,5,4,0,0,2,95,
0,0,0,5,4,0,0,6,7,
0,0,0,5,4,0,0,4,30,
0,0,0,5,4,0,0,4,190,
0,0,0,5,4,0,0,4,189,
0,0,0,5,4,0,0,2,47,
0,0,0,5,4,0,0,1,19,
0,0,0,5,4,0,0,0,28,
0,0,0,5,4,0,0,0,223,
0,0,0,5,4,0,0,2,75,
0,0,0,5,4,0,0,4,33,
0,0,0,5,4,0,0,1,31,
0,0,0,5,4,0,0,1,100,
0,0,0,5,4,0,0,6,24,
0,0,0,5,4,0,0,3,181,
0,0,0,5,4,0,0,4,94,
0,0,0,5,4,0,0,2,99,
0,0,0,5,4,0,0,6,44,
0,0,0,5,4,0,0,0,74,
0,0,0,5,4,0,0,6,9,
0,0,0,1,1
```

A BitTorrent *peer to peer* connection consists of two unidirectional byte streams, one in each direction. When reading the data stream from the receive buffer, don't expect to get exactly one complete message per time. You must yourself split the stream to messages. Also, be prepared for that the responding peer likely will start to send messages immediately following after the end of the **handshake**.

Comment: Thanks, that was helpfull, i think i should use some kind of buffer for peer messages, at current point i'm parsing every incoming message as separate one